# Change button text and action present in custom dialog box

Tags: android, android-button, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog box which consist of some text and a "next" button. Now, If my application finishes and ends, then the same custom dialog box appears but I need to change the button text with "close" and so the respective action. Here is the code:

```
    private void CustomizedDialog(String text1, String text2) {
final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(this);
customDialog.getWindow();
customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

TextView firstTextView = (TextView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
firstTextView.setText(text1);

TextView secondTextView = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
secondTextView.setText(text2);
    if (currentInfo == (information.size() - 1)) {
    View closeButton = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.answer_next_button);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    } else {
        View nextButton = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.answer_next_button);   

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("next button", "next button clicked");
                customDialog.dismiss();
                if (currentInfo < (information.size() - 1)) {
                    currentInfo++;
                    nextInformation();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    customDialog.show();
}
```

How can i change next button and its associated action in the custom dialog box with the close button and its action when the application reaches its end? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your conditionals are ok, you should access the first condition if it's the last entry, to change the text you simply need to cast the `View` to a `Button` and call the `.setText(String t)` method:

```
Button closeButton = (Button)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.answer_next_button);
       closeButton.setText("Close");
```

As for the *associated action* it all seems correct, just add any other actions inside the `onClick` method of the first condition.